# Eclipse duplicates package and its resources upon renaming

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rename

Try to **refactor->rename** a package and it creates a new package while still keeping the old package (and every resource under it). Should refactoring not only rename but also move everything from the old package to the new one?

I am using Eclipse Oxygen and a Java Maven project.

Comment: That's not how it works for me. Did you make sure to tick the options "Update references" and "Rename subpackages" in the Rename Package dialogue window?

Comment: Since you have provided maven as a tag I'm assuming you renamed a package within a Maven project. Can you update your post (as opposed to adding a comment) with details of the project structure and what specific folder you renamed? A simple reproducible example would be ideal. Also, specify the version of Eclipse that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works by checking off options with

> update packages, 
>   rename subpackages